# Как подставить ячейку как название листа в формулу google spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet, excel-формулы, formula

Есть google spreadsheet с несколькими листами: Sheet1, Sheet2 и тд с данными. На отдельном(сводном) листе все названия листов перечислены в столбик и рядом должны быть суммы данных.

К примеру, сейчас используется формула `=SUM(Sheet1!F:F)`. Как можно вместо `Sheet1` указать название из ячейки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция листа *ДВССЫП (INDIRECT)* позволяет задавать ссылку текстом. Текст может быть написан в формуле или в другой ячейке, на которую ссылается функция.

Функция *СУММ(SUM)* не умеет самостоятельно определять диапазон пользователя. Чтобы уменьшить лишние вычисления, диапазон желательно задавать ограниченный:

```
=СУММ(ДВССЫЛ(D3&"!F2:F5000"))
=SUM(INDIRECT(D3&"!F2:F5000"))
```

Если в имени листа возможно наличие пробела, нужно добавить апострофы. Диапазон в ссылке можно сделать относительным, если вынести его из текста:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&D3&"'!"&F2:F5000))
```